# iphone google meet link not join room

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-meet

I'm trying to open Google Meet link from iOS like this:

```
if let link = URL(string: "https://meet.google.com/\(MeetingCode)") {
  UIApplication.shared.open(link)
}
```

But this can not join room successfully sometimes, only open meet application or gmail application
and not instruct to join room

Comment: I don't think it is your app problem, did you try to open the link from other applications. Try to send the link through any social app and open it from there, what will happen? same as your app or it will open successfully

Comment: Thank for comment, I will try it. This problem was replied from our user, I'm curious why this problem sometimes occurs, I can't even test it out.